# unable to connect to pgadmin dashboard using minikube ip

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, pgadmin

I am not able to connect to pgadmin dashboard although the IP seems to be valid.

```
minikube ip
192.168.49.2

minikube service pgadmin --url 
http://192.168.49.2:30200
```

When I am trying to reach the service through the browser, it is not opening.

```
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          3d23h   <none>
service/pgadmin      NodePort    10.108.140.131   <none>        80:30200/TCP     11m     app=pgadmin     
service/postgres     NodePort    10.104.164.196   <none>        5432:30432/TCP   11m     app=postgres
```

#EndPoint Output

```
NAME         ENDPOINTS           AGE
kubernetes   192.168.49.2:8443   4d
pgadmin      172.17.0.5:80       84m
postgres     172.17.0.6:5432     85m
```

kubectl logs pgadmin-6df4b6c978-l28gt

```
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

[2022-03-01 12:27:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-03-01 12:27:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
[2022-03-01 12:27:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2022-03-01 12:27:39 +0000] [89] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 89
```

Comment: Assuming that your minikube instance is hosted at `192.168.49.2`, that all looks fine. Have you confirmed that the `pgadmin`  pod itself is running? What does `kubectl get endpoints` show?

Comment: @larsks updated the description with endpoints

Comment: What is end log in pgadmin log

Comment: @SounakSaha updated the description

Comment: Just to understand your network connectivity. Are you able to access 192.168.49.2:30432 from any pgclient?

Comment: Can anybody explain me why I am able to access the pgadmin service with my host ip (which I found out using ipconfig in cmd) and not through the minikube cluster ip